# Unexpected status line: Y������ when using getInputStream() on HttpURLConnection

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache, http

I am trying to connect to a mysql database using an HTTP request. I have created a class which extends AsyncTask ad takes care of making the http post request and retrieving the data. Here's my code:

```
public class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask {

        String mUserName;
        String mPassword;

        String un = "admin01";
        String pass = "admin01";
        Connection con;
        Context context;

        AlertDialog dialog ;

        public AttemptLogin(Context context, String mUserName, String Password) {
            this.context   = context;
            this.mUserName = mUserName;
            this.mPassword = Password;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            dialog.setTitle("Login Status");
        }

        protected  void onPostExecute(String s){
            dialog.setMessage(s);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            try{

                Log.d(tag, "Debut do in background");
                String constr = "http://000.000.0.00:3306/login.php";
                URL url = new URL(constr);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                http.setDoInput(true);
                http.setDoOutput(true);
                http.setUseCaches(false);
                http.setRequestMethod("POST");
                http.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

                OutputStream ops = http.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ops,"UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mUserName, "UTF-8") + " & " +
                              URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mPassword, "UTF-8");

                writer.write(data);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                ops.close();

                String result = "";
                String line = "";

                InputStream ips = http.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"ISO-8859-1"));

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    result += line;
                }

                Log.d(tag, "Result = " + result);

                reader.close();
                ips.close();
                http.disconnect();

                onPostExecute(result);

                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
    }
```

Of course, the IP I've placed is just to hide my real IP. 
Anyway, the line at getInputStream() is returning the following error:
Unexpected status line: Y������

I've tried many things incuding setting the "Connection" property to "close" but it didn't work out.

Any help would be appreciated as I've been stuck for some time now.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to make an HTTP request to a port which runs an MySQL-specific protocol. The request happens, but the response is not an HTTP response, thus the exception.

Comment: I did that according to some tutorial on YouTube. Following your advice, I removed the port number and it all worked just fine. Thanks a million!